# issue with JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

hi guys i don't know why but i get this error: `JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`.

I show you my code!I hope that you can help me! thanks in advance everybody!

Sorry, but i am new to `JSON`.

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = " http://v1.tvguideapi.com/programs?channels[]=2161&channels[]=2162&start=1484598600&stop=1484605799";
    //private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("programs");
                   // JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");


                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                  /*      String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        String email = c.getString("email");
                        String address = c.getString("address");
                        String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String office = phone.getString("office");*/

                        String title=c.getString("title");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                      /*  contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("email", email);
                        contact.put("mobile", mobile);*/
                        contact.put("title",title);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                   /* MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                    "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile});*/
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title"}, new int[]{R.id.title});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "18879971",
    "start": "2017-01-16 20:20:00",
    "stop": "2017-01-16 22:30:00",
    "lang": "",
    "title": "Il Collegio</td>",
    "subtitle": "",
    "description": "",
    "category": "",
    "channel_id": "2162",
    "icon": null,
    "ts_start": 1484598000,
    "ts_stop": 1484605800
  },
  {
    "id": "18879856",
    "start": "2017-01-16 20:25:00",
    "stop": "2017-01-16 22:40:00",
    "lang": "",
    "title": "I Bastardi di Pizzofalcone",
    "subtitle": "",
    "description": "Ep.3 - In un fatiscente condominio di Pizzofalcone viene rinvenuto il cadavere di una camariera. Le indagini della squadra portano al marito della donna, ma per Lojacono il caso si complica ulteriormente.",
    "category": "",
    "channel_id": "2161",
    "icon": null,
    "ts_start": 1484598300,
    "ts_stop": 1484606400
  }
]
```

Comment: `jsonStr` is `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

Comment: so i must write this?                     JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

Comment: Yes, remove `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);` and `JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("programs");`  line and write `JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);`

Comment: and where i write the name of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use you have Json Array.

you have [{ },{}] format Here [] shows JsonArray and {} this is json object.

you can have Json array loop through array and get Json object.

```
JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

Instead of using

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Now you can fetch data

```
     for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        //Get all required data using c.

             String id = c.getString("id");
             String name = c.getString("start");

         }
```

Comment: you have [{ },{}] format [] shows JsonArray and {} this is json object

Comment: you can check data using Logs provided by android.

Comment: SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter use this.